# Turned bytes string and saved. Is it possible to get the original bytes back

Tags: python

I took a Python bytes object returned by a method and assigned it to a text column in a database. I meant to call decode on the bytes prior to saving. Is there a way to take the string representation of that bytes object and turn it back into bytes so that i can call decode and re-save it?

The string in the database is:

```
\x30316331643763386665356566663764303761626132633030373931376531343835616334623136346131633633663564663235393532656361373663353966
```

I'd like to be able to read that into bytes somehow but can't quite figure out the correct way to instantiate it so that I can make the decode('utf-8') call I missed the first time.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks something like"? Why can't you show a portion of the real string?

Comment: Added real string.

Comment: Can you give some idea of what the original text looked like? What language was it written in? Did it contain non-ascii characters?

Comment: The original string would have been hex. Specifically a call to decode('utf-8') would have been made on the bytes to get the string i need.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just say exactly what the original string was? Why are you forcing people to guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify("30316331643763386665356566663764303761626132633030373931376531343
835616334623136346131633633663564663235393532656361373663353966")
'01c1d7c8fe5eff7d07aba2c007917e1485ac4b164a1c63f5df25952eca76c59f'
```

unhexlify **might** be what you are looking for, this particular example unhexlify's to what looks like maybe some sort of hash

Comment: Didn't occur to me to drop the \x from the start. Perfect, thanks.